# coordinate grid of divs, coloring jquery

Tags: jquery

I happen to be around a very specific problem which is hard to identify.

I have quite a long code, and I cannot narrow it down because I don't know what exactly is what I don't know or where exactly is the problem.

Here is the code: http://codepen.io/julian-a-avar/pen/EaLozR

All I know is that the problem is somewhere between `line 116` and `line 177`, but if I narrow the code to that part, the code itself wont be functional anymore.

To make things easier, I decided to put a link to my code instead of copying the code here.

**My problem is the following:**

I have made a way so I can see when a plot has been selected. Once I press *"colonize"* the plot that is selected is suppose to replace the same exact properties as object `you`.

What happens is that JQuery, somehow, seems to record which squares I clicked and change every single square I clicked before to the `you` properties, and not only replace the properties of the plot selected at the moment like it is suppose to.

Comment: This code does not look very optimal, if you have got it working as intended by now, you might want to consider posting it at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get it cleaned up. (be sure to include the code in the question itself)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I prefer to not make someone else work that hard on this. It is an independent project. Plus I'm trying to learn and not get something done no matter what. But thank you for the offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had several issues with the code:

- you attached a click handler to the "colonize" button on each div click, this should not be done inside the click handler. -**i moved the click handler for the colonize button outside of the div click handler.**
- instead of returning the color to black on div blur, its simpler to color them all black and color `$(this)` to white - **done**
- the `plot_id` and `obj` vars should be global and only assigned in the div click handler, that way you can access them from the colonize click handler as well. - **done**
- the `plot_info` function needs to be moved outside of the handler as well. there is no reason to recreate this function each time you click on a div. - **done**
- you had a global var named `plot_info`, i didnt bother checking what its used for, but it had same name as the function above. if you need this var, then rename it to something else. - **i removed the var for now.**

here is your fixed <kbd>[**Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVPVmr)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    var i;
    var plot_id;
    var obj;

    function plot(building, terrain, temperature, humidity, population, money, goods_produced, corruption_level, owned_by) {
        this.building = building;
        this.terrain = terrain;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.humidity = humidity;
        this.population = population;
        this.money = "$" + money;
        this.goods_produced = goods_produced;
        this.corruption_level = corruption_level + "%";
        this.owned_by = owned_by;
    }

    var you = new plot("little houses", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "33", "you");
    var barbarian = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "5", "barbarian");
    var user = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "70", "user");

    var AA = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var AB = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var AC = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "5", "barbarian");
    var AD = new plot("castle", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "5", "barbarian");
    var AE = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "5", "barbarian");
    var AF = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var AG = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var AH = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var AI = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");

    var BA = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var BB = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var BC = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var BD = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "5", "barbarian");
    var BE = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "5", "barbarian");
    var BF = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var BG = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var BH = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var BI = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");

    var CA = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var CB = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var CC = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var CD = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var CE = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var CF = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var CG = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var CH = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var CI = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");

    var DA = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var DB = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var DC = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var DD = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "33", "you");
    var DE = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var DF = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "33", "you");
    var DG = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var DH = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var DI = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");

    var EA = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var EB = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var EC = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var ED = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "33", "you");
    var EE = new plot("castle", "soft", "warm", "normal", "1000", "1000000", "none", "33", "you");
    var EF = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "33", "you");
    var EG = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var EH = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var EI = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");

    var FA = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var FB = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var FC = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var FD = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "33", "you");
    var FE = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "33", "you");
    var FF = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "33", "you");
    var FG = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var FH = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var FI = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");

    var GA = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var GB = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var GD = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "33", "you");
    var GC = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "33", "you");
    var GE = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "33", "you");
    var GF = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var GG = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var GH = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "70", "user");
    var GI = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");

    var HA = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var HB = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var HC = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var HD = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var HE = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var HF = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var HG = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "70", "user");
    var HH = new plot("castle", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "70", "user");
    var HI = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");

    var IA = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var IB = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var IC = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var ID = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var IE = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var IF = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var IG = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "0", "no one");
    var IH = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "70", "user");
    var II = new plot("none", "soft", "warm", "normal", "0", "0", "none", "70", "user");

    function plot_info() {
        $("#coordinates").text("(" + plot_id.toLowerCase().split("") + ")");
        $("#building").text(obj.building);
        $("#terrain").text(obj.terrain);
        $("#temperature").text(obj.temperature);
        $("#humidity").text(obj.humidity);
        $("#population").text(obj.population);
        $("#money").text(obj.money);
        $("#goods_produced").text(obj.goods_produced);
        $("#corruption_level").text(obj.corruption_level);
        $("#owned_by").text(obj.owned_by);
    }

    function color() {
        $("#map").children("div").each(function () {
            var plot_id = this.id.toUpperCase();
            var obj = eval(plot_id);

            switch (obj.owned_by) {
                case "you":
                    $(this).css({
                        "background-color": "red"
                    });
                    break;
                case "user":
                    $(this).css({
                        "background-color": "yellow"
                    });
                    break;
                case "barbarian":
                    $(this).css({
                        "background-color": "blue"
                    });
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
    color();

    $("#map div").click(function () {

        plot_id = this.id.toUpperCase();
        obj = eval(plot_id);
        $("#map div").css({
            "color": "black"
        });
        $(this).css({
            "color": "white"
        })

        plot_info();
    });

    var $colonize = $("#colonize_land");
    $colonize.click(function () {
        console.log(obj);
        if (obj.owned_by === "no one") {
            for (i in you) {
                obj[i] = you[i];
            }
        } else if (obj.owned_by === "you") {
            //              alert("you own this already");
        } else {

        }
        plot_info();
        color();
    });
});
```

Comment: Jesus Christ! How did you do that! That was amazing! You have solved all my problems in less than an hour! I have to congratulate you! And thank you very much, you are indeed one of the best programmers I've met. Thank you very much, julian